# Use Views to display unpublished nodes to authors, but not to other users

Tags: 7, views, users

Say [User A] creates, but does *not* publish [Node 1]. [Views V] aggregates all of the content type that [Node 1] belongs into. [User B] should not be able to see [Node 1] listed on [Views V], but [User A] should be able to see his *own* unpublished [Node 1], all through [Views V] which lists out the specific content type.

Currently, if I change the Filter to not filter for Published or Unpublished nodes, then regular members can see the *title* of unpublished Nodes through the view, despite not having permission to access it (if the user clicks on it, then access denied message is shown). I do not wish for this to occur. However, I can't explicitly filter out unpublished nodes, since I want authors of said nodes to be able to see them (and access/edit them before publishing).

So is it possible to have Views filter out nodes based on the access permission of the current user?

I am using Drupal 7, and Views 3.

Comment: if you found a solution, I guess that you can post your answer like an answer, because somebody can not review your answer at the end of your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just to save anyone else some time and trouble, there's a filter under Views called, "Content: Published or admin." This will do precisely what is needed.